# THREE.JS : How do I dynamically change a specific face for a JSON loaded model?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl, blender

I have a JSON loaded mirror that I would like to hook up to a webcam. The mirror's reflection will be updated with video coming from a canvas. I was able to follow this source http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_materials_video
to display a video on a canvas.

However, I need the video texture to run on the specific face of the object. I've tried targeting the object via geometry.faces[i]materialIndex to no avail. The animation is moving, so having a plane to emulate that the the texture is on the model is also not optimal. Is there any advice on what to do?

Comment: can you give us a screen shot where the video is expected to be on what face, how is the model moving...is it just positions or is it bones or morphing... visual would probably help so i can understand what you are trying to do..also faces are two triangles so you will have to find both triangles for one face using face index to compare

Comment: Sure, Careen. The model is currently the banner of this website.. www.therearenoends.com . The mirror is the figure's mask. His mask is a mirror. And yes, it is two triangles.